# Pass list to google distance matrix, returning only single value

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps

I want to use Googles [distance matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) API to measure the road distance between multiple addresses and a single address. I have a list of origin Latitudes and Longitudes (list_o), and destination Latitudes and longitudes (list_d). My Api key is set up.

```
list_o

[(51.268369, -1.361543),
 (51.368369, -1.361043),
 (51.062992, -1.250635),
 (51.910508, -1.314208),
 (51.233251, -1.551402)]
```

```
list_d

[(53.423451, -1.462141),
 (53.483451, -1.172141),
 (51.423451, -1.262141),
 (52.623451, -1.246211),
 (52.323451, -1.462141)]
```

if I pass in the lists of addresses

```
result = gmaps.distance_matrix(list_o, list_d, mode='walking')["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"]
```

I only get a single result, eg 34000 metres = 34km , which looks correct.
I have tried appending the result to a list and it still only comes up with one result.

With

```
gmaps.distance_matrix(list_o, list_d, mode='walking')["rows"][0]["elements"]
```

I am getting 10 values (the full size of the df, above I only showed the first 5).

```
{'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'},
 {'distance': {'text': '34.0 km', 'value': 34014},
  'duration': {'text': '7 hours 6 mins', 'value': 25554},
  'status': 'OK'}]
```

However they are all the same value.

Comment: How does `gmaps.distance_matrix(list_o, list_d, mode='walking')["rows"][0]["elements"]` look?

Comment: see above edit, interesting but strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is using:

```
list_o

[(51.668369, -1.361043),
 (51.668369, -1.361043),
 (51.662992, -1.270635),
 (51.610508, -1.314208),
 (51.733251, -1.351402)]
```

and:

```
list_d

[(52.423451, -1.462141)]
```

And then call:

```
results = gmaps.distance_matrix(list_o, list_d, mode='walking')
```

The results you are looking for are:

```
# Distance between first origin and destination.
# I.e.: distance (51.668369, -1.361043) -> (52.423451, -1.462141)
results['rows'][0]['elements'][0]

#... and so on
```

In other words, `results['rows'][i]['elements'][0]` is the distance of location `i` to the destination.

`gmaps.distance_matrix` calculates the distance between the origins and each of the destinations.

Comment: Thats great has worked a treat, - I  couldnt see in any documentation where ['rows'][0], or ['rows'] [i]  is defined?, or did you just know, -as you can tell I am not that accomplished in this.

Comment: I knew, but you can see it in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_results): "`elements` are children of `rows`, and correspond to a pairing of the row's origin with each destination."